# php only extension using godaddy cpanel website not loading on browser,

Tags: php, xampp, cpanel

I upload an index.html file and it renders, but when I remove that file and try index.php, the page is entirely white.

This is what I have done so far:
I built a website using XAMPP, and everything renders fine on my computer. I'm using CPANEL (GoDaddy) and dragged and dropped the files and folders to public_html, however, the index.php file does not load, it's just completely white. I built this site with PHP because I did not want to repeat my headers and footers, I also have a contact form. Nothing else too fancy.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a fatal error with PHP. Have you tried enabling error reporting?

Add the following to your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You should now be able to see the fatal errors (if any) and act accordingly to resolve those.

Alternatively, if you are on cPanel or DirectAdmin, both provide access to the server's error log in the panel so that you can view that too ('Errors' in cPanel and 'Site Summary -> Error Log' in DirectAdmin).

Most common reasons for a fatal error include incomptabile (too new or old) PHP version, missing PHP extensions, out of memory limit, etc.

To increase memory limit, you can add the following to your PHP file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512MB');
```

To change PHP version or extensions, you can refer to your host's guide, on cPanel you can locate "MultiPHP Manager" to select the PHP version of your choice.

Hope this helps!